# D3 graph not updating with uniform data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm working on a bar chart. Strangely enough, the bar chart works fine for unique data, but when updated with data that is exactly the same, the graph does not update. It is not a scale/spacing problem, as the `rect`'s representing the data aren't being generated at all.

[Here is a JSFiddle demonstrating my problem](http://jsfiddle.net/ckucera3/pyLh7tcn/32/).

### More information

The bar chart is given data in the following form:

```
    data.push({
        temperature: 10,
        humidity: 20,
        light: 30
    });
```

The bar chart creates a separate bar for each attribute. The attributes are represented by this type object, to help with spacing and naming the bars:

```
// type objects
typeObject = {
    temperature: {
        string: "temperature", //type name
        class: "temp",         //css class for styling
        initDis: 0,            //defines where to place first bar
        dis: 3,                //defines space between the next temp bar
        base: tempBase,        //the <g> element base
        color: "#A6E22E"       //color
    },
    humidity: {
       ...
    },
    ...
};
```

And, every time data is added, these type objects are iterated through and passed into the following function, to make a d3 'update pattern':

```
var createBarsForCategory = function (type) {
    var bars;
//`data` has been updated to an array containing newly added data
bars = type.base.selectAll("rect")
    .data(data, function(d) {
        return d[type.string];
    });

//general update transition
bars.transition().duration(500).attr("x", function(d, i) {
    return i * (m.bar.w + m.bar.space) * type.dis + m.bar.w * type.initDis;
});
// enter
bars.enter()
    .insert("rect")
    .attr("class", type.class)
    .attr("width", m.bar.w)
    .attr("height", function (d) {
        return 0;
    })
    .attr("x", function (d, i) {
        return i * (m.bar.w + m.bar.space) * type.dis + m.bar.w * type.initDis;
    })
    .attr("y", function (d) {
        return scales.yscale(0);
    })
    .transition().delay(100).duration(1000)
    .attr("height", function (d) {
        return scales.yscale(0) - scales.yscale(d[type.string]);
    })
    .attr("y", function (d) {
        return scales.yscale(d[type.string]);
    })
;

// remove
bars.exit().remove();
};
```

Thank you in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pyLh7tcn/33/ with the following code on lines 173-178:

```
bars = type.base.selectAll("rect")
    .data(data);
```

Now both random and uniform data sets are plotting properly.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the contribution, it now works. I neglected to mention that there is an animation that is supposed to play once the bars reach the end of the frame. Once the frame is filled up, the bars slide to the left as the oldest piece of data is removed. **With your solution, the bars no longer animate as old data is removed.** I will accept the answer, and any further help getting this to work is appreciated.